How to solve: Type mismatch: inferred type is (PuQuPrintManager) -> Unit but () -> Unit was expected
Testing Bluetooth connection with mobile printer.
I am getting "Type mismatch: inferred type is (PuQuPrintManager) -> Unit but () -> Unit was expected"
compiler error.
I am lost in this, It seems ok with other function but this line cannot figure out what I did wrong.
MainActivity
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    when {
                        state.isConnecting -> {
                            Column(
                                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
                                ) {
                                CircularProgressIndicator()
                                Text(text = "Connecting....")
                            }
                        }

                        else -> {

                            DeviceScreen(
                                state = state,
                                onStartScan = viewModel::startScan,
                                onStopScan = viewModel::stopScan,
                                onDeviceClick = viewModel::connectToDevice,
                                onStartServer = viewModel::waitForIncomingConnections,
                                onTestPrint = viewModel::testPrint
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }

DeviceScreen
@Composable
fun DeviceScreen(
    state: BluetoothUiState,
    onStartScan: () -> Unit,
    onStopScan: () -> Unit,
    onStartServer: () -> Unit,
    onDeviceClick: (BluetoothDevice) -> Unit,
    onTestPrint: (PuQuPrintManager) -> Unit
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        BluetoothDeviceList(
            pairedDevices = state.pairedDevices,
            scannedDevices = state.scannedDevices,
            onClick = onDeviceClick,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .weight(1f)
        )
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround
        ) {
            Button(onClick = onStartScan) {
                Text(text = "Start scan")
            }
            Button(onClick = onStopScan) {
                Text(text = "Stop scan")
            }
            Button(onClick = onStartServer) {
                Text(text = "Start server")
            }
            Button(onClick = onTestPrint) {
                Text(text = "Test Print")
            }
        }
    }
}

BluetoothViewModel
    fun testPrint(pqManager: PuQuPrintManager) {

        pqManager.openPrinter(bluetoothController.pairedDevices.value[0].address)

        pqManager.startJob(180, -1)
        pqManager.addText("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -")
        pqManager.setLeft(50)
        pqManager.addBlank(24)
        pqManager.addBarCode("12345678", 200, 100)
        pqManager.setLeft(16)
        pqManager.addBlank(80)
        pqManager.addText("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -")

        pqManager.printJob()

    }


Android Studio error is "DeviceScreen.kt Type mismatch: inferred type is (PuQuPrintManager) -> Unit but () -> Unit was expected----->            Button(onClick = onTestPrint) {
Text(text = "Test Print")
}    ---> but OnDeviceClick fun has argument, works fine........

You can't put onTestPrint on an onClick because it wouldn't know what argument to use

OnDeviceClick is call in DeviceScreen.kt which has (BluetoothDevice) --> which later called on BluetoothViewModel.kt connectToDevice(device: BluetoothDevice)                     fun connectToDevice(device: BluetoothDeviceDomain) {
_state.update { it.copy(isConnecting = true) }
deviceConnectionJob = bluetoothController
.connectToDevice(device)
.listen()
}
